# How to quickly "exit" git soft reset?

Tags: git

So I decided to go back a couple of commits to check a previous state. So I do this:

`git reset --soft {commit_hash}`

Is there a way to quickly go back to latest changes, instead of doing soft reset again, but this time with the commit hash of latest change?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout to the branch (switch to the latest commit of the branch).

```
$ git checkout <branch-name>
```

Simple tricks: `git checkout -` will checkout you to the last commit you were.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --soft` is not meant to examine previous state in history: it does not change your worktree, *but it does change the branch you are on*. You should have used `git checkout <commit-to-examine>` instead. Then, coming back to where you were is as simple as

```
git checkout -
```

To cancel the effect of your `git reset --soft`, best is to find the commit you were on and run

```
git reset --soft <that-commit>
```

Hopefully, this commit is the last one your branch were on, and then you can run

```
git reset --soft @{1}
```